# How can I get a hostname from an IPv4 address in C?

Tags: c, function, ip-address, hostname, ipv4

I need a simple function that outputs a `char* hostname`, given a `char* IPAddress`. Any ideas or hints?

Also, is easiest way to get the IP address from a hostname is `gethostbyname()` and `inet_ntoa()` is that correct?

Comment: Note that the `inet_ntoa()` only converts in memory from a `sockaddr` structure to a string in numeric notation. No support for domain names.

Answer (score 5):

Use `gethostbyaddr()` or `getnameinfo()` to convert an IP into a hostname.

Use `gethostbyname()` or `getaddrinfo()` to convert a hostname into an IP.

`gethostby...()` only support IPv4. `get...info()` support multiple protocols including both IPv4 and IPv6, and are the preferred functions for new development.

Answer (score 3):

All the information you need on this is in the excellent [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html). The page relevant to your question is [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html).

If after reading that, you are still having problems, post here with a question about a specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. To get the host name from an address, you normally use (big surprise here) [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/gethostbyaddr/).
2. Yes, probably.