# List of connections shows 0.0.0.0 in C socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

My code accepts incoming connections and stores them in an array.

```
if(i == sockServer){
                    //handle incoming connection
                    addrlen = sizeof(remoteaddr);
                    sockClient = accept(sockServer, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);
                    if(sockClient < 0){
                        perror("Accept failed: ");
                    }else{
                        FD_SET(sockClient, &master);
                        if(sockClient > fdmax){
                            fdmax = sockClient;
                        }

                        IpList[connectionCount] = remoteaddr;

                        connectionCount++;
```

The later in the code when I try to iterate the array and print out the Ip address and port numbers of the connections I get the following.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < connectionCount; ++i)
                            {
                               struct sockaddr_in tempSock = IpList[connectionCount];
                               printf("%d  %s  %d\n", connectionCount, inet_ntoa(tempSock.sin_addr), ntohs(tempSock.sin_port));

                            }

0  0.0.0.0 0
1  0.0.0.0 0
```

The array is statically allocated array

```
struct sockaddr_in IpList[256];
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing this (in the cycle where you are printing the connections):

```
struct sockaddr_in tempSock = IpList[connectionCount];
```

to this:

```
struct sockaddr_in tempSock = IpList[i];
```

should hopefully fix it :)

Comment: That was really embarassing. But just as an afterthought, could you help me get the host name from the ip address.

Comment: Use gethostbyaddr? Also, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082787/how-can-i-get-a-hostname-from-an-ipv4-address-in-c